# Copying to SVN Tag Using Team City

Tags: svn, teamcity

I would like to create a build in Team City that copies from a known svn location and copies it to a tag location and deletes/overwrites it if it exists.

I know how to do this via SVN.exe, but wanted to see if this was possible using Team City.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a build step with the command line runner.